# Armory issues on macOSX

Tags: bitcoin-core, armory, mac

I bought BTC a few years ago and stored them in cold storage. I encrypted it and saved it in google drive.

Some time ago I decided to check on it. But I couldn't open Bitcoin Armory at all, so in the end I downloaded it via terminal (with cask and homebrew). And that worked!

I opened it, saw I had money but for some reason I couldn't send it. Whenever I would press send button, nothing happened.

So, I reinstalled it a few times and still nothing.

So, I decided a few days ago to delete entire blockchain, remove Bitcoin Core and Armory and remove all files from application support and start over.

Now, I finally downloaded the blockchain with pruning and Armory is stuck on organizing blockchain for a few days now.

[image: Armory issue]

So, today I decided to export the keys into Electrum but Electrum says there no Bitcoins inside of it...

I am worried that in the process I didn't accidentally lose them.

**My question is, should it take this long? 
And what can I do to speed it up, to get to the funds faster?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Armory does not work if the blockchain is pruned. You must have the full blockchain in order for Armory to work.